# Changing a link into a button in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My function is correctly displaying a link, but I would prefer it to be displayed as a button. I tried using addClass() as follows, but but it still just displays as a link:

```
 var attachUrlHtml = groupPlay.AttachmentFileName.link(groupPlay.AttachmentUrl);

  $('@Html.IdFor(model => model.GroupPlayInput.Attachment)').addClass("btn btn-default");

 var attachUrl = document.getElementById('@Html.IdFor(model => model.GroupPlayInput.Attachment)');
 attachUrl.innerHTML = attachUrlHtml;
```

edit: forgot to show the div to which it refers:

```
<div style="padding-top: 5px;" id="@Html.IdFor(view => view.GroupPlayInput.Attachment)">
    @if (Model.GroupPlayInput.Attachment.IsNotNull())
     {
       <a href="@Model.GroupPlayInput.Attachment.Url" target="_blank">@Model.GroupPlayInput.Attachment.Url</a>
     } 
 </div>
```

Comment: the classes 'btn btn-default' are from twitter-bootstrap I guess? Is the bootstrap css fully loaded? Can u inspect the generated html in your browser and see if the correct classes are set

Comment: When you inspect the link, does it actually have the `btn btn-default` classes?

Comment: Is bootstrap imported before this is called?

Comment: yes the css is defintely loaded as other bootstrap button are displaying correctly on the page.  Inpecting the element shows that the 'btn btn-default' class has not been added

Comment: It seems you are missing the `#` in `$('#@Html.IdFor(model => model.GroupPlayInput.Attachment)').addClass("btn btn-default");`. But wouldn't it be easier to add the `btn btn-default` classes inline in the HTML?

Comment: Angela you are absolutely right I forgot the # in the selector.  I'm sorry to have wasted all your time. :(